Two-airline trip: is it worthwhile to buy a more expensive ticket allowing more luggage?
I consider to book a trip via Singapore airlines website. One leg of the trip is operated by El-Al.
If I buy an "Economy Lite" ticket, I get 25 kg baggage; I can buy a more expensive "Economy Flexi" ticket, which gives me 30 kg baggage.
My question is: can I be sure that El Al will respect the fact that I bought "Economy Flexi" from Singapore Airlines, and let me take 30 kg baggage in the first leg?
I did not find an answer in their website; in their website, they just say that their standard baggage allowance is 23 kg, but do not relate to special tickets bought through other companies.

Is this a single ticket with two legs on different carriers, or two separate tickets?

A single ticket with two legs on different carriers. I book the entire trip through Singapore Airlines website.

The ticket tell you what you can transport: if they tell you you can take 30 kg, you can take it. it is about entire travel (for checked baggage). Extra allowance is common: different class, ticket type, extra, frequent flyer benefit, etc.

I do this often with Condor. The ‘feeder’ flight is with Lufthansa, never had a problem with the checked baggage allowance bought via Condor. In fact, several times LH has let me get away with a kilo or so more than the booked allowance, without charging me. One thing to be wary of though is luggage dimensions, which can vary. So if I were you I’d check permitted baggage size for both airlines before booking.

@GiacomoCatenazzi I do not have a ticket yet, as I still have not decided whether to buy the cheap or expensive ticket. If the expensive ticket is not recognized in the first leg, then of course it is a waste of money to buy it.

@ErelSegal-Halevi: a) where is your layover? b) have you checked that the price difference to the Flex ticket is less than just paying for extra weight/piece?

Baggage rules when travelling on multiple airlines can be difficult, and can vary based on the country that your journey starts in, and specific flights involved with the flight. What's more, the rules can be different in one direction than in another.
Singapore Airlines has a page on their website describing their different fare types, and this page explicitly states that

Do note that the conditions that apply to your fare type are only
applicable on flights operated by Singapore Airlines. If you are
travelling with a partner airline, their conditions of carriage will
apply.

You mentioned "El Al" and "first leg" together, so I'm presuming that you are starting out with them at least for one of your directions of travel.  Presuming this flight doesn't originate in the USA, then the "IATA Resolution 302" rules would likely apply. These rules are a little complex, but Air New Zealand has a somewhat simplified version of them here that you can look at to determine who's baggage rules would apply for this flight.
If El Al is the "Most Significant Carrier" for your flight, then the Singapore Airline baggage rules will most likely not apply, and you will be charged under the El Al rules.  If Singapore Airlines is the Most Significant Carrier then your 30kg limit should apply.

On that page it states that the most significant carrier is now based on the marketing carrier, not the operating carrier. Given that the marketing carrier for a code-share flight bought as a single ticket is almost always the airline selling the ticket, doesn't that make the whole MSC question redundant, as the marketing carrier for a El Al operated Singapore codeshare would be Singapore?

@user1937198 El Al is not listed as a codeshare partner for SQ on their website, so presumably the marketing carrier for this flight is El Al.  However even if it was a codeshare it still fits in the "it depends" category - the official Resolution 302 statement on this is "In case of code-share flights, in general the Marketing Carrier's baggage policy prevails, unless that carrier publishes a rule stipulating that the Operating Carrier’s baggage policy should apply.".  So it's marketing carrier, unless it's not!

All this information is not for the passenger to know or find out. Singapore airlines will not sell a single ticket that has a greater hold baggage allowance than a connecting flight. It will state clearly on the booking what the hold baggage allowance is for the entire trip.
